# Retrieving a value from database through a query and showing in dropdown + if/elseif

Tags: php, html, sql

My website contains a page to add data to a database. Now I'm working on the output of that data and making it able to edit it, if necessary.

On my add page, I have a dropdown with several options. If selected, that value goes to the database. Now I want to reverse it. Select the value from the database and show it in a dropdown with the same values as on the add page. But the value from the database needs to be default selected.

In my code I only try with 2 values, but should be easy to add more if this codes works.

**code:**

```
<?php
    $A = "A";
    $B = "B";
    $query  = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id='$id'");

    while ($record = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
    {

        echo "<table>";
            echo "<tr>";
                echo '<td><b>Type: </b>

                            <select name="type">
                                if ($record['type'] == "A"){                    
                                    echo "<option selected value ="' . $A . '">A</option>";
                                    echo "<option value="' . $B . '">B</option>";
                                } elseif ($record['type'] == "B"){
                                    echo "<option selected  value="' . $B . '">B</option>";
                                    echo "<option value="' . $A . '">A</option>";
                                }
                            </select>

                      </td>';
            echo "</tr>";
        echo "</table>";
    }
?>
```

I think I'm missing some "" or '' quotes somewhere.

Comment: you can see it in the basic syntax highlighting above.. it's your use of single quotes in `$record['type']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your if's are inside a string because you've not closed the echo, therefore they are being handled as strings and not actual code.

```
<?php
    $A = "A";
    $B = "B";
    $query  = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id='$id'");

    while ($record = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
    {

        echo "<table>";
            echo "<tr>";
                echo '<td><b>Type: </b>

                            <select name="type">';
                            // You were missing closing '; on the line above

                                if ($record['type'] == "A"){                    
                                    echo "<option selected value ="' . $A . '">A</option>";
                                    echo "<option value="' . $B . '">B</option>";
                                } elseif ($record['type'] == "B"){
                                    echo "<option selected  value="' . $B . '">B</option>";
                                    echo "<option value="' . $A . '">A</option>";
                                }

       // Dont forget to then open the echo again              
       echo '              </select>

                      </td>';
            echo "</tr>";
        echo "</table>";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are already used one `echo` Don't want use multiple echo for display one string.

```
echo '<td><b>Type: </b>
                            <select name="type">'.
                                if ($record["type"] == "A"){.'                    
                                    <option selected value ="' . $A . '">A</option>
                                    <option value="' . $B . '">B</option>
                                .'} elseif ($record['type'] == "B"){.'
                                    <option selected  value="' . $B . '">B</option>
                                    <option value="' . $A . '">A</option>.'
                                }.'
                            </select>
                      </td>';
```

Other way is using Concatenate with variable is:

```
$A = "A";
    $B = "B";
    $query  = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id='$id'");
    $tbl = '';

    while ($record = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
        echo "<table>";
            echo "<tr>";        
              $tbl .= '<td><b>Type: </b>
                            <select name="type">';
                    if ($record["type"] == "A"){
                        $tbl .= '<option selected value ="' . $A . '">A</option>
                                <option value="' . $B . '">B</option>';
                    } elseif ($record['type'] == "B"){
                        $tbl .= '<option selected  value="' . $B . '">B</option>
                                <option value="' . $A . '">A</option>';
                    }
                    $tbl .= '</select>
                        </td>';
              echo $tbl;
            echo "</tr>";
        echo "</table>";
    }
```